# java application cannot insert null value into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, textbox

I'm making a java program using `Netbeans`, I want to insert data into my "`data supplier`" table. I cannot post my `JFrame` picture as my reputation is not enough.

I've set `"Kode Supplier`" as `PRIMARY_KEY` and `NOT_NULL`, and allow the rest to be `NULL`

In the code below, `telpField` and `hpField` will show an error if I didn't type anything in it's textbox

Is it possible because it is `INT` type?

This is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{

        String sql = "INSERT INTO datasupplier (`Kode Supplier`, `Nama Supplier`, `Contact Person`,"
                + " `Alamat`, `NoTelp`, `NoHP`, `Bank Account`, `A/C Info`, `A.N.`, `Keterangan`)"
                + "  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    //Get value from the textboxes
    pst.setString(1, codeField.getText());
    pst.setString(2, nameField.getText());
    pst.setString(3, cpField.getText());
    pst.setString(4, addressField.getText());
    pst.setString(5, telpField.getText());
    pst.setString(6, hpField.getText());
    pst.setString(7, bankField.getText());
    pst.setString(8, acField.getText());
    pst.setString(9,anField.getText());
    pst.setString(10, ketField.getText());

    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tabel Telah Di Update");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Invalid");
    }
    DataSupplierTable();
}                                        

//Set JComboBox First Diplayed Item
private void setTableCombo(){
  tableCombo.setSelectedItem("Data Supplier");
}


//Bind the table and databarang.datasupplier
private void DataSupplierTable(){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM datasupplier";
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        supplierTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        supplierTable.isCellEditable(0,0);



    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

This is my table (using MySQL Community Server Database, InnoDB)

```
Kode Supplier    INT(30) PRIMARY_KEY NOT_NULL,
Nama Supplier    CHAR(45),
Contact Person   VARCHAR(20),
Alamat           VARCHAR(45),
NoTelp           INT(30),
NoHP             INT(30),
Bank Account     CHAR(30),
A/C Info         VARCHAR(45),
A.N.             CHAR(45),
Keterangan       VARCHAR(100)
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Yes, it's probably because it's integer type. You don't use `setString` for integer fields. Why don't you add your table definition?

Comment: @Rahul The error message is: "java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: for column 'NoTelp' at row 1"

Comment: Thank you both for replying, @RealSkeptic I've updated my post and add my table contents(I'm not sure if that's what you mean by table definition), what do you suggest I should use in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is because your `Kode Supplier`, `NoTelp` and `NoHP` columns are integer columns. For integer columns, you should be using the `setInt` method rather than `setString`.

But the [`setInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29) method only accepts an primitive `int` for the value of the field. So the first thing you'll need to do is convert the `String` value of the field to `int`. This is done with a statement like:

```
int telpVal = Integer.parseInt(telpField.getText());
```

But this means you have to decide what to do in the following cases:

- The user entered a value in the GUI field which is not an integer, like `ABC`, `1.2` or `123456789123456789`. If that happens, then the statement I gave would throw a `NumberFormatException`.

  You could decide to display an error message and not call the insert statement when this happens. Or you may decide to insert a `NULL`. Or you may decide to insert a default value like `0`.
- The user entered no value in the GUI field - it is an empty string. Note that there is a difference between an empty string and a `null`. You may decide to handle this case the same way you handle the previous one. Or you may decide to handle it separately.

Suppose you decide that:

- If the user entered an illegal number, you'll show an error message and will not insert the row.
- If the user did not enter a value and left the field empty, you want to insert a null.

Then you'll need to handle it like this:

```
String fieldName;

try {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO datasupplier (`Kode Supplier`, `Nama Supplier`, `Contact Person`,"
            + " `Alamat`, `NoTelp`, `NoHP`, `Bank Account`, `A/C Info`, `A.N.`, `Keterangan`)"
            + "  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    //Get value from the textboxes

    // Kode supplier is integer, but is not allowed to be null
    // so don't handle an empty field case, just let parseInt
    // throw the exception.

    fieldName = "Kode Supplier";
    pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(codeField.getText()));

    pst.setString(2, nameField.getText());
    pst.setString(3, cpField.getText());
    pst.setString(4, addressField.getText());

    // Handle the NoTelp field - if empty, insert null. If not,
    // parse the number. Handle illegal number values in catch.

    fieldName = "NoTelp";
    if ( telpField.getText().isEmpty() ) {
        pst.setNull(5, Types.INTEGER);
    } else {
        pst.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(telpField.getText());
    }

    // Handle the NoHP field

    fieldName = "NoHP";
    if ( hpField.getText().isEmpty() ) {
        pst.setNull(6, Types.INTEGER);
    } else {
        pst.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(hpField.getText());
    }

    pst.setString(7, bankField.getText());
    pst.setString(8, acField.getText());
    pst.setString(9,anField.getText());
    pst.setString(10, ketField.getText());

    pst.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tabel Telah Di Update");
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // Display error to the user
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number in field " + fieldName)
}
catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Invalid");
}
```

**Notes**

- I handled `Kode Supplier` differently than `NoTelp` and `NoHP` because it is not allowed to be null. If the field is empty, `NumberFormatException` will be thrown from `parseInt` and will go to the `catch` part.
- I kept a `fieldName` variable which I set before trying each `parseInt`. If an exception is thrown, we can use it for displaying the specific field where the error occurred in the dialog box. You can do other things like keeping the `JTextField` that you are currently handling, and in the `catch` highlighting it and giving it focus.
- When you use [`setNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29), you have to pass the type of the field as the second parameter. All the types are in `java.sql.Types`. So remember to `import java.sql.Types`.
- Don't use a `catch (Exception e)`. It's too broad. In this case we expect only `NumberFormatException` and `SQLException`. If any other exception happens, especially a runtime exception, you want to know about it and see the stack trace. If you have `catch (Exception e)` you'll just get a dialog box that says "Data Invalid" and that is not helpful. "Catch all" is bad.

Comment: I see.. you need to parse the INT type before it can be stored, thank your for catch(error) advice, thank you very much for your very detailed information.